# How to Display Terms for all posts in Current Archive or Query in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I have custom post types with select option.In select option I got all the taxonomy categories and on change of select it displayes all posts of post type but when I go to single page it displayes only this current post not all from this category. I tried this code 
`$term = $wp_query->queried_object;` but it displayes only the current post of this category not all.

How can I get all posts from the current taxonomy category.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems I got the solution.Here is my final code

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'course_type' );
if($terms){
// post has course_type terms attached
$course_terms = array();
foreach ($terms as $term){
 $course_terms[] = $term->slug;
}
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'courses',
'tax_query' => array(
 array(
'taxonomy' => 'course_type',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => $course_terms, //the taxonomy terms I'd like to dynamically query
'posts_per_page' => '-1'
  ),
),
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC'
) );
if ( have_posts() ): ?>
<ul>
 <?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?     php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;
 wp_reset_postdata(); 
} // end if($terms)
```